# unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I working on a program that recalls data from various text files and displays it in a variety of user chosen ways. I'm not very familiar with Python and there are probably a lot of errors in my code. When I run the code I get an `unexepected EOF while parsing` error. Does anybody know what is wrong here?

```
from time import sleep
import sys

for i in range(21):
    sys.stdout.write('\r')
    sys.stdout.write("[%-20s] %d%%" % ('='*i, 5*i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(0.25)

print('\nWelcome to The Arithmatic Quiz: Teacher Eddition.')

UserName = input('Please input your user name and press enter.')

if UserName == 'MrSmith':
    print ('Please proceed.')

else:
    quit()

Password = input('Please input your password and press enter.')

if Password == 'Maths':
    print ('Welcome Mr Smith.')

else:
    quit()

import csv
import operator

classdata = 0
while classdata == 0:

    Class = input ('Which class do you want the data for?')

    Display = input ('How do you want the data t be sorted? Alphabetically      (A), on highest score for the first try (H1), on highest score for the second try (H2), on highest score for the third try (H3), or average score (Avg)?')

if Class == '1':
    Class_1 = open('class_1.txt','r')

    csv1 = csv.reader(Class_1,delimiter=',')

    if Display == 'A':
        sortA = sorted(csv1,key=operator.itemgetter(1))

        for eachline in sortA:
            print (eachline)

    if Display == 'H1':
        sortB = sorted(csv1,key=operator.itemgetter(2))

        for eachline in sortB:
            print (eachline)

    if Display == 'H12':
        sortB = sorted(csv1,key=operator.itemgetter(3))

        for eachline in sortB:
            print (eachline)

    if Display == 'H3':
        sortB = sorted(csv1,key=operator.itemgetter(4))

        for eachline in sortB:
            print (eachline)

    elif Display == 'Avg':
        sortC = sorted(csv1,key=operator.itemgetter(5))

        import csv
        from collections import Counter

        def average_column (csv_filepath):
            row_totals = Counter()
            with open('Class_1',"rb") as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f)
                column_count = 0.0
                for column in reader:
                    for row_idx, row_value in enumerate(column):
                        try:
                            n = float(row_value)
                            row_totals(row_idx) += n
                            column_count += 1.0
                            column_count -= 1.0
                            row_indexes = row_totals.keys()
                            row_indexes.sort()
                            averages = (row_totals(idx)/column_count for idx in row_indexes)
                            print(averages)
```

If it helps, I'm running Python 3.4.3

Comment: Could you please post at least a piece of you input file(s). Also, you're posting quite a bit of code, could you be more specific, have you debugged and you know where it is failing? The more info you provide, the more likely you will get a good answer. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Why do you think that you don't use `input` function? And try to make your code as small as it is only possible (i.e. try to make minimal example where this problem is reproducible).

Comment: Error is produced directly by unclosed Try/expect instruction.

Comment: My .txt files are just names and numbers, I don't know if that helps...

Comment: However the overall structure of the code is very messy. The part starting from `import csv` looks like copypasted from somewhere. You need to watch for indentation in python. Your pasted function should be probably starting at 0 indentation level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `except` portion of your `try`/`except` loop at the end of your code. If you have a `try` statement you must have an `except` statement as well, if you don't it will give you the error that you see. Here is the portion of code that is missing the `except` statement:

```
try:
    n = float(row_value)
    row_totals(row_idx) += n
    column_count += 1.0
    column_count -= 1.0
    row_indexes = row_totals.keys()
    row_indexes.sort()
    averages = (row_totals(idx)/column_count for idx in row_indexes)
    print(averages)
except:   # here is the except statement you were missing
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks @MarkyPython, that's fixed it.